# Как устранить ошибку при обновлении репозиториев Maemo?

Tags: linux

При обновлении репозиториев maemo выводится ошибка:

> `GPG error: https://downloads.maemo.nokia.com ./ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ADB4438160A655EF
> W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems`

Что она означает и как от нее можно избавиться?

Answer (score 2):

Причина происхождения проблемы — отсутствие в вашей системе публичного GPG-ключа репозитория, из которого вы пытаетесь инсталлировать пакет. Не знаю, что такое maemo, но в debian и ему подобных делается примерно так:

```
gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv ADB4438160A655EF
gpg --export --armor ADB4438160A655EF | sudo apt-key add -
```

Прочитал, что такое maemo, собственно она тоже производная debian, так что всё должно быть ок! )

Comment: Попробовал, пишет следующее:
> gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv ADB4438160A655EF
gpg: requesting key 60A655EF from hkp server subkeys.pgp.net
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: eof'''
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0<

Comment: если я правильно понимаю такого ключа на данном сервере нет...Может надо попробовать другой сервер ключей...